# Cant get Element of List in Numpy

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am trying to calculate the sum of all `1d matrices` in a list (as the code below), but I can't get the element of the output array.
I cant explain the reason why?

Here is my Code:

```
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce 
matrix = np.matrix([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[1,1,1]])
my_sum_matrix = reduce(lambda x,y : x + y, matrix)
print (my_sum_matrix)
print (my_sum_matrix[0])
```

And this is output :

```
[[4 6 8]]
[[4 6 8]]
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: [[4 6 8]]
 [4 6 8]

Comment: i want to get the list inside, but i relize i cant get any element of that list

Comment: `print (my_sum_matrix.tolist()[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Numpy `matrix` type should only be used when you *really* need it. For more general work, you should use the `array` type. And you don't need `reduce` for this task.

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [1,1,1]])
my_sum_matrix = np.sum(matrix, axis=0)
print(my_sum_matrix)
```

**output**

```
[4 6 8]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I understood